# C# Generics Question

Tags: c#, generics

Would it be possible to do something like the following in c#?
Basically TParent and TChildren should be types of the class A but *not* necessairly have the same types that were passed in. I know this may sound confusing but I want to strongly type the children and parents of a particular object, but at the same time they must be of the same type. Because TParent inherits from A this would imply that it requires type parameters that inherit from A but using potentially different types.

```
public class A<TParent, TChildren> 
    where TParent : A
    where TControls : A
{
    TParent Parent;
    List<TChildren> Children;
}
```

or more easily seen here:

```
public class A<TParent, TChildren>
    where TParent : A<?, ?>
    where TChildren : A<?, ?>
{
    TParent Parent;
    List<TChildren> Children;
}
```

I hope this isn't too confusing. Is this at all possible?

Thanks :)

Comment: Just to clarify the question: You want to have 2 generic parameters of the same *Type*, but you do not want them to be the same instance.

Comment: @Michael Stum - Both generic parameters *could* be the same type but there is the possibility that they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.  One workaround, however, is to create a subclass of `A<TParent, TChild>` and enforce that the generic type parameters are of that type:

```
public interface A
{
   // some properties and methods
}

public class A<TParent, TChild> : A where TParent : A where TChild A
{
   // something else here.  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to say "The parent must have this type as a child and the child must have this type as a parent" then I think the answer is no, you can't, because you'd also need to know the type of the parent's parent and the child's child.

However, you can do this

```
public interface IHasChildren<T>
{
    List<T> Children { get; set; }
}

public interface IHasParent<T>
{
    T Parent { get; set; }
}

public class A<TParent, TChildren> : IHasChildren<TChildren>, IHasParent<TParent>
    where TParent : IHasChildren<A<TParent, TChildren>>
    where TChildren : IHasParent<A<TParent, TChildren>>
{
    public List<TChildren> Children { get; set; }
    public TParent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible.  The closest you can come is to define another base type, and require TParent and TChild to inherit from that:

```
public class A { }  // or an interface

public class A<TParent, TChild> : A
  where TParent : A
  where TChild : A
{ }
```

Which doesn't guarantee you that TParent and TChild are of the generic `A<,>` type, but does at least allow you to place some constraints on them, which the `A<,>` implementation can take then assume.